# Documentation file (User Manual) for a MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, documentation, html-helper

I would like to create a help file (similar Matlab help documentation) for a Matlab GUI that I have built. I do not how to make this really. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: see MATLAB Publishing here: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f6-14058.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at MATLAB publishing, as suggested by Mikhail, to produce your documentation. To integrate your documentation into MATLAB's, take a look at [Adding Documentation to the Help Browser](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f3-40511.html).